# Linker error on Mac but not on iOS for any C++ function

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, cocos2d-x

**Long version**: I'm looking to implement my app's model in C++ and use this model everywhere that Cocos2d-x uses C++ so that: (1) I know it has the same version of C++ and (2) I can remove my application's model from Cocos2d-x when the time comes. I'm starting with Mac OS X and iOS, and I'm making sure things compile before I set out with this project. On iOS, everything is working just fine. On Mac, basic C++ gives me a linker error every time!

**Short version begin**: I have a C++ class that looks like the following:

```
class GetInteger {

public:
    static int GetInt();
};
```

All's well so far, so let me go ahead and define my super-complicated static function:

```
int GetInteger::GetInt()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Okay, that's basic C++, I'm now going to go ahead and use my super-complication function:

```
"include "GetInteger.h"
...
int theInt = GetInteger::GetInt();
...
```

Things are still super-simple, and in fact, it all works when I compile this code in Xcode for iOS, using the standard settings for a Cocos2d-x project for iOS. But when I try to run this code on a Mac, it get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GetInteger::GetInt()", referenced from:
      AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is this? How do I resolve this?

Here's my project file from [ZippyShare](http://www25.zippyshare.com/v/76930073/file.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition save's my ton's of effort @PLJNS , whoever wants detail can walk through the following steps.

say you have **XYZ.h** & **XYZ.mm** which causes the problem.

***solution::***

1. select XYZ.h & XYZ.mm and delete them, in the delete dialogue choose "Remove Reference"[image]
2. Now Add XYZ.h & XYZ.mm by "Add Files to your_project_name".[image]
3. Now Select All of your target (here i select two of mine MobileDialerNewSt & IPA).
   [image]
4. Clean & Build.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Objective-C files have extension `.mm` and not `.m` and try compiling again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that any file you include must be added to both targets, I just saw that piece of UI this minute. That fixed my issue.

**BE SURE TO INCLUDE ALL YOUR FILES TO ALL YOUR TARGETS WITH XCODE**